# A fluid full-height bootstrap layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a game layout which fills the entire browser window, but doesn't scroll. The layout is something like this:

```
 +----------------------+
 +       Header         +
 +------+---------------+
 +      +               +
 +      +               +
 + Side +    Main       +
 +      +  Fill Height  +
 +      +               +
 +      +               +
 +----------------------+
 +       Footer         +
 +------+---------------+
```

The sidebar should scroll if necessary, but the main content should not. The layout should be responsive: if the browser is too narrow the side goes under "header" and switches the way it is presented (likely Footer disappears as well).

I'd like to use Bootstrap but I can not find any details on how such a layout might be possible. Does it make sense to even use the bootstrap layouts in this display? Or should I rather just code the CSS with absolute positions (% based) and used bootstrap widgets within the sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create this type of layout by putting the sidebar and main content in a 100% height/width wrapper.

See this example template at Bootply: http://bootply.com/102032

EDIT: Pad the sidebar_wrapper according to the height of the header and footer:

```
  #sidebar-wrapper {
      height: 100%;
      padding: 50px 0 50px 0; /* pad top and bottom by height of header and footer */
      position: fixed;
      border-right: 1px solid gray;
  }
```

Comment: The footer doesn't appear to work correctly. Notice the left panel appears to go behind the footer (the scroll bar is clipped).

Comment: I update the answer and Bootply: http://bootply.com/102032 -- pad the sidebar accordingly.